# R Spectral density / frequency for time series with unequal steps

Tags: r

For a time series `x` with even time-spaces between each observation, `spectrum(x)`, `fft(x)` and several other functions can be used. However, I now find myself faced with a time series that is meausured at unequal intervals. `x` are the time measurements (in days) and `y` are the variable measurements.

I have tried `spectrum(y~x)` but gotten nowhere, only generating an error. I know `spectrum` can accept a multivariate time series, but that is not what I am looking for.

Are there any functions to do this?

Comment: See the lomb R package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a regularly spaced ts with `NA`'s for each value where an observation is missing, you can make it work, but be careful with your interpretation(s) if there are lots of `NA`. For example,

```
> set.seed(123)
> dat <- sin(seq(100)/(12))
> dat[sample(length(dat),5)] <- NA
> ## this fails
> spectrum(dat)
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
> ## this works
> require(tseries)
> spectrum(dat, na.action=na.remove)
```